# 'find -mtime' fails to return results that 'ls -l' show are there

Tags: linux, find, ls

On a Red Hat Linux system, I have a directory with several hundred files. I wanted to delete all files older than 24 hours. I did the deletion using `find . -type f -mtime +1 -delete`. Trivial stuff, right? Then, while checking the results, I discovered that `ls -l` reports files older than 24 hours in the directory. Note the date below, and the result of the last find:

```
> date
Sun Jan  5 19:02:43 PST 2014
> find . -type f -mtime +1 | wc -l
0
> find . -type f | xargs /bin/ls -l | grep 'Jan  3' | wc -l
70
```

Curiously, there are no files older than about 48 hours. (There definitely were before.) At this point, however, I'm well and truly stumped. I'm probably missing something obvious, but what? Can someone please enlighten me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `find`, "+1" means greater than 1.  Further, when computing age in days, it rounds down to the nearest integer.

This behavior is documented in the man page:

> When find figures out how many 24-hour
>                 periods ago the file was last accessed, any fractional part is ignored,  so  to
>                 match -atime +1, a file has to have been accessed at least two days ago.

In your example, those two full days means that it should have found files only if they were older than Jan  **3** 19:02:43.  Any file made after that on Jan 3 would not be found.

So, when you wrote "Curiously, there are no files older than about 48 hours", that means that `find` is behaving exactly as documented, however perverse that might be.

Comment: The man page on the system I was running at the time (which happened to be a Mac running OS X 10.8) did not mention the "at least two days ago" part. However, the Red Hat man page *does* mention it, and therein lies a lesson in checking the man page on the (remote) system one is *actually* running a command on, not the system used on one's laptop :-(.  In any case, both man pages do mention the fractional part issue, and that should have been enough to figure it out. Thank you for solving this, and the helpful info.

Comment: @mhucka I have seen the issue of Mac man pages being different come up before.  I'm curious whether the Mac `find` is different or just its Mac man page.